# R, tmap: Changing labels in view mode

Tags: r, maps, tmap

I'm working on a map with tmap and i'm having some trouble changing labels in view mode as in
[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gV8dI.png).

I'm trying to change it to cities names column using `name` argument like:

```
tm_shape(mymap, name = "city_name") +
  tm_polygons("Inad", palette = "Reds", title = "")
```

but it keeps showing the first column as label, which is cities codes (320120 for example).

Is `name` the right argument to accomplish so?

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `id` argument:

```
 tm_shape(mymap) + tm_polygons("Inad", id="city_name" palette="Reds", title="")
```

Answer (score 0):

The following is likely to do the trick:

```
tm_shape(mymap) +
  tm_text(text = name_var_in_your_shapefile)
```

If you supply a sample link or other way for replicating, we can test it out. For documentation on tm_text have a look [here](https://rdrr.io/cran/tmap/man/tm_text.html)

Comment: Didn't work. I've got Error: Incorrect data variable used for the text when inputing shapefile's names column. Btw, tm_text supposed to print text over the plot all the time, right? Anyway, i just changed columns order, so it's done.